# Weird CSS3 margin issue

Tags: html, css

I'm currently following through a tutorial video on the Team Treehouse website, and there's this strange issue I can't figure out.

I uploaded the practice site here: http://www.oneniceday.com/about.html

Basically, I'm trying to add a 10% top margin to the entire section below the horizontal navigation links bar.

So, in the appropriate ID, I added a 10% margin to the top:

```
#wrapper
{
max-width: 940px;
margin:10% auto;
padding:0 0%;
background-color:black;
}
```

However, for some strange reason, although the margin top value is applied to the #wrapper class, it seems the browser somehow applies it to the H1 class, and now the H1 class has a 10% margin at the top! (which is why you see a big gap above the green row if you look at my site)

What's wrong with this?

Tks!

Comment: The margin is applied to the `body` element, and why that happens has been discussed quite often already. It is an explicitly specified effect called [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the `header` has `float: left;`, and there's really no reason for the `header` to have that property.

If you added float to fix the margin of `h1` you could instead add this "clearfix":

```
header::before {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```